# VLOOKUP from Previous Sheet

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have spent several hours trying to figure out how write the correct code so I don't have to change it every month. I am trying to do a vlookup from the previous months sheet. I found a site that said to use '" & ActiveSheet.Previous.Name & "'. When I use this I get close but it triggers a file open box. I select the current file and then it has me select a sheet. Ultimately, the code in the cell ends up being =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L4,'[ Dec ]Dec'!$L:$AC,12,FALSE),"") instead of =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(L4,Dec!$L:$AC,12,FALSE),""). How can I avoid having to select the current file and sheet? My code is below.

Your help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Sub Justification()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

Dim lastrow As Long 
Dim i As Integer 

lastrow = Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  

Range("J3:J" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'V:\CORPDATA02\D0003\ISSHARE\Accruals\2020\[Justification.xlsx]sheet1'!C1:C6,6,FALSE)" 
Range("L3:L" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]&RC[-4]" 
Range("U3:U" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]-RC[-1]" 
Range("V3:V" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(SUMIF(C[-14],RC[-14],C[-1])<25000,""UNDER 25K"",""YES"")"

Range("W3:W" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11],' " & ActiveSheet.Previous.Name & " '!C12:C29,12,FALSE),"""")" 

For Each Cell In Range("Y3:Y" & lastrow) 
If Cell = "0" Then Cell.Clear
Next Cell 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You could just create the formatted month name with a bit of logic based on `Date`.

Comment: why are there spaces before and after  the sheet name reference? I mean here`' " & ActiveSheet.Previous.Name & " '` ' is used when sheet name has spaces, is that the case for you? With your syntax the sheet name is ' Dec ' rather than 'Dec'

Comment: Stachu, thank you for your help! That fixed the problem!